As is a tale, so is life
As is a tale, so is life. Advice on life (see:7:24-7:28)
I looked "as is" up, but it doesn't seem to fit in this sentence.
Does the sentence mean life is a tale? What kind of structure is that?

As others have remarked, bear in mind that this saying  is not  in contemporary  English syntax but is deliberately modeled on an ancient text in Latin.

When you say that you looked up "as is", I guess you found a meaning like this from the Cambridge Dictionary:

in the state that something is in at the present time

In this case, though, "as is" is not intended to be the idiomatic expression defined above: the two words are intended to be taken separately. Often in proverbs and maxims, the word order is adapted to make it sound nicer- sometimes at the expense of clarity. In this case, a clearer way of saying it would be:

as a tale is, so is life

or even

Life is like a tale


Whatever you think of Rowling's writing (let alone her politics), she's never been accused of being a great stylist. This is a clumsy phrase.
However the full sentence makes things a bit clearer:

As is a tale, so is life: not how long it is, but how good it is is what matters.

In other words:

Just like with a story, the important thing about life is not the length but how good it is.


It's actually modeled after Classical Greek and Latin constructions, which she did study. I suspect that's where it comes from.

Let's keep politics, and even oblique references to it, off this site, shall we?

In fact, she says herself that it is a quotation from Seneca. By googling some likely Latin words, I found that the original is
Quomodo fabula, sic vita; non quam diu sed quam bene acta sit, refert

I'm with her on her anti-Trump and ant-Brexit stance, and opposed to her gender-critical views, and I hate her books and the characters in them.

I'm used to thinking that the 'as is... so is...' thing is just a literary way of saying something. Only 'awkward' if you like simple stuff written after 2010.

And to misquote Woody Allen, "Her potions are swill and the portions are so small."

@KateBunting Exactly, and this style is common in Greek and Roman aphorisms. Cf. Homer's οἵη περ φύλλων γενεὴ τοίη δὲ καὶ ἀνδρῶν. I don't see anything clumsy with it, and Seneca has his haters, but clumsy he is not.
